How to seal existing shiplap ceiling
I purchased a condo, the HOA is not replacing my roof, and my roof is basically dead. I do not have insulation in between the shiplap and the plywood and the roof shingles, or what is left of them. There is no attic space and this is not an issue of water leaking, as the HOA has patched the leaks as I report them. I get a ton of dust coming through, especially when it's windy, just random specks and chunks of things on my bed, I believe to be deteriorated plywood/roof stuff. The shiplap is not damaged, just old and never sealed. I want to seal the shiplap ceiling so that nothing is coming through (dust, dirt, debris). Would I have to caulk each gap, seam and wood hole with a clear caulk, or what about spraying a wood sealer, if so, what kind? or would I need to brush or roll it on being above my head? Would a simple wood sealer actually seal the holes and gaps? Multiple coats? The gaps are not big at all, the largest knot hole is maybe a dime size, at most. I do not want to paint it, as many neighbors have done to theirs, I like the wood look.
I know the HOA sucks and is legally obligated to replace the roof, my attorney is dealing with them legally, but until then I'm just trying to figure out what I can do myself to help myself... That's all I have control over. I know sealing the ceiling will not fix the roof, but is there harm in sealing the shiplap? because I think it's a great idea even with a new roof. I have no insulation and it would probably save me money in heating and cooling AND keep the dust out.
Also all new builds using shiplap, they seal them before install, so that's why I'm asking this question, the conditions are different in my case and I may need to use something different and use a different technique.

If the HOA is legally obligated to replace the roof, and it actually needs replacing, then your problem becomes a legal one rather than a home improvement one. No sealer applied to the ceiling will fix a roof leak.

Yes, I'm dealing with the legal side with my attorney but as I stated I'm trying to fix what I have control over and that's sealing my ceiling to keep out the dust and particles of whatever is coming in.

Is the roof actually leaking water, or is the problem the dust that's raining down on you? Roof spaces are rarely (if ever) completely airtight, so air (and consequently dust) movement up there is perfectly normal. What is not normal is to have a lot of gaps in your ceiling which allow the dust to rain down on you inside - but this is likely your problem to fix and not the HOA's.

Try stapling plastic to the ceiling.  Doing anything to the roof structure could possibly jeopardize or muddy the waters of the Condo issue.  I do know in many places the courts allow for condo owners to seek relief, ( do repairs) on their own, ( hiring professionals) Then recover the cost from the condo association later.

I'm not sure how to respond to a particular comment, but when it does leak water the HOA will fix the leak. So it's the dust and what I assume is deteriorated plywood or whatever else is on the other side of the shiplap... so I am trying g to figure out what is the best way to seal it and still look nice, so no plastic.

Sealing and making it "look Nice' does not repair the damage. It is just kicking the can down the road to be a larger issue in the future.

Can you take a photo? I think you're suggesting that your ceiling is shiplap against the open roof cavity? If so, that not correct and is your problem.

Is there attic above your ceiling?  Is it accessible?  Is it insulated?

There is no attic, they are vaulted ceilings, there is no damage to the wood shiplap, the wood has wood knots/holes and some of the seams do have gaps. And until the roof gets replaced, dust and things are coming through. People paint their ceilings mine is dry brushed, most of these ceilings, the boards are sealed before installing in today's install but this was installed in the 70s. I'm just trying to find out what would be the best way to seal them as they are existing.

Can you lay a tarp on the roof from outside?

Even after the roof is replaced you're still going to get dust & things coming through... so you're going to have to come up with a long-term/permanent solution to the gaps in your ceiling. If your neighbors have all painted theirs then you might have to end up don't the same (in the hope of filling in all the gaps between the boards). If you like the wood look then maybe a clear sealer product of some sort.

Yes that was why I asked the questions for sealer, spray, roll, or brush and what kind. I do not want to paint it, just seal it

Based on question and comments.  The objective is to temporarily prevent or reduce the amount of outside debris (but not water) coming through gaps in the roof without repairing the roof and without using plastic sheeting while the legal path takes its course.  Start with knot holes and large gaps, fill those with spray foam then cut or file down to flush with ceiling.  Then do smaller gaps, focusing on ones where you actually see dirt coming through and working your way to smaller ones until there is no more benefit.  Switch from foam to caulk when the gaps become small enough
This will reduce the problem a little.  It won't keep water out.

Thank you, that is a good idea, but with them being so small would a clear caulk be a better option?

Yes.  Noted in answer.

Thank you, and with just focusing on the gaps and holes, the wood can still breath and shrink and expand with the temperature. I just installed butcher block countertops in my kitchen and my main bathroom and reading how they need to be able to move... thanks so much for your help.

Sure.  I'm not recommending this.  Putting tons of caulk all over the ceiling will be very hard to reverse and clear caulk doesn't always look great.   I'm just answering the question which, as others have pointed out, is not the ideal approach to your problem.
